# iPhone 11 Pro Max with iOS 13 Camera permission issue

Tags: ios, permissions, camera, ios13.3

My iOS App need to take photos from camera or need to select from photo library. 
I have the entries in the plist and do the "`AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess`" to request permissions.

And **App is working fine so far in all iPhones except iPhone 11 pro max.** in iPhone 11 Pro max It does not prompt user for camera permissions and also in the settings it doesn't show and entry like below.

If any one has an Idea to fix this issue you are welcome to answer.

iPhone 8 with iOS13.3 shows the camera permission in settings page
[image: **Expected Result** iPhone 8 with iOS13.3 shows the camera permission in settings]

[image: **Actual result** iPhone 11 Pro max with iOS13.3 no camera permission in settings]

iPhone 11 Pro max with iOS13.3 no camera permission in settings page

Comment: Will you please write switch case for authorizationStatus(for:)
and debug it.
I think, you'll find something for sure.

Comment: @NiravKotecha If I have not asked the permission how can it be working fine one all other iPhones except Pro Max?.

Comment: @RahulPatel  I'm waiting for a pro Max device to debug. So far all the testing devices I have don't show this issue.

Comment: Guys please read the Question " App is working fine so far in all iPhones except iPhone 11 pro max. "

Answer (score 0):

I have find the cause to the issue. it is a restriction in iOS settings.

Settings > Screen Time > Content & Privacy Restrictions > Allowed Apps > Camera > is turned off

[image]